# Converting .plist to xml

Tags: ios, xml, jenkins, ui-automation

I'm new in test automation and i have the task to show report after build procedure is done and my test cases are also finished. But i have no idea how to convert .plist file to any suitable format like xml for Jenkins and the better straight to html with images. Maybe some one have already faced with similar issue and can advice me.

Please note that i'm absolutely newbie in this. I found solution that suitable for me at http://blog.essencework.com/post/1728269540/xcode-uiautomation-for-test-result-report-part-2. But i really don't know how i can realize it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could read the .plist file in to the Objective C object, depending on its structure (`NSArray` or `NSDictionary`). Then you can generate xml data for later use (save it to the file, or send by network). You can use this third party library to generate XML from NSDictionary:
[XMLDictionary](https://github.com/nicklockwood/XMLDictionary)

Good Luck!

Comment: Thanks for answer but maybe there is some easy way to solve my problem?

Comment: What do you mean by easy way? This is already an easy way :). Of course, you could write your own XML generator, that also would not be an easy way.

Comment: I mean maybe there is a ready solutions like plugins, scripts ant etc.